# SQL Server 2008 Trigger Insert Latitude & Longitude and Update Geography Field

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers, insert, geography

Hi Folks: I'm trying to write a trigger that fires after insertions into a Points table in SQL Server 2008. I've made a first attempt that appears to be working, but no matter how I change the values for latitude and longitude in subsequent insertions the geography field remains exactly the same

```
USE GIS

IF EXISTS(SELECT name FROM SYSOBJECTS WHERE name = 'PointCreationTrigger' and type = 'TR')
DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[PointCreationTrigger]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[PointCreationTrigger] 
   ON  [dbo].[Points] 
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Point AS GEOGRAPHY
    DECLARE @Longitude AS FLOAT
    DECLARE @Latitude AS FLOAT
    DECLARE @WKT AS VARCHAR(256) -- well known text representation of a point

    SET @Longitude = (SELECT i.Longitude FROM inserted i)
    SET @Latitude = (SELECT i.Latitude FROM inserted i)

   IF @Latitude IS NOT NULL AND @Longitude IS NOT NULL
   BEGIN
        IF @Latitude > -90 AND @Latitude < 90 AND @Longitude > -180 AND @Longitude < 180
        BEGIN
            SET @WKT = (SELECT 'POINT(' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(16),@Longitude) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @Latitude) + ')')
            SET @Point = geography::STGeomFromText(@WKT, 4326);
            UPDATE [dbo].[Points] SET Point = @Point
        END
    END
END
GO
```

Any suggestions...?

Comment: Have you made sure that `@Latitude` and `@Longitude` are within limits? E.g. the `IF` statement is executed.

Comment: You cannot assume only one record will ever get inserted, this trigger won't work if multiple records are inserted in the same statement. You should always test triggers with multiple record inserts as well as single record inserts.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the SQL you currently have into a single update statement that affects all of the rows included in the statement that fired the trigger.

See @HLGEM 's comment, and take note. Triggers only fire once per SQL statement, and need to take into account all the rows that were affected by that statement.

```
update
    p
set
    Point = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), i.Longitude) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), i.Latitude) + ')', 4326)
from
    inserted i
inner join
    dbo.Points p
        on p.PointsID = i.PointsID
        and i.Latitude > -90
        and i.Latitude < 90
        and i.Longitude > -180
        and i.Longitude < 180
```

**Assumption:** You have one or more PK fields to join on.

**Suggestion:** To make this more robust, you should probably conditionally set the `Point` value to be `NULL` if the `Latitude` or `Longitude` are not valid values.

**Alternate possibility:** This may not fit your needs, but you could alternately store the string version of the point data in a persisted calculated column in the table, removing the need for a trigger. The downside of this is that it has to be a varchar column instead of a geography datatype, so if you're actively using the geography datatype, this approach means more converting. The trigger will only perform the conversion once.